# Upgrading project installshield 2008 to installshield 2013

Tags: upgrade, installshield

I have .ism file which is designed by installshield 2008, and then I successfully built MSI file by command line(using IsSABld.exe -p).

Then I convert this .ism file into installshield 2013 (by open IT in installshield 2013) now I want to build .msi file by command line(using IsCmdBld.exe -p), but its building .exe file not .msi file.

I installed installshield 2013 trial version, is this problem by trial version or by any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes trial version compresses all files into one .exe file. You need to get licensed one.

Comment: i have 1 more question ,  how to give license to IsCmdBld.exe. license required at time of installation of installshield 2013 ? or we can give license at run time with IsCmdBld.exe . is it required to install installshield 2013 at every server ? or we can save ism file by installshield 2013(license version) at only one server then we can use that ism file ?  please tell me ......